# Screen recorder permitting of specify the exact position of the recording area

Tags: screen-recording

I'm looking for a screen recording software in Mac or Windows.

I hope the software could let me specify the exact position of the recording area. For example, the position of the left top point, and the width and height (in pixels) of the recording area.

Does anyone know if such a recorder exists?

PS:

OBS:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use [OBS](https://obsproject.com/).
There are may options for input (both video and audio) and most also have some adjustment options like cropping the sides.

[image: crop options]

From your question it seems like you should use `Display capture`. But there might be something better like `Window capture`. If you use `window capture`the recording stays with the selected window even if you are using another window.

There are also more advances options like overlays (e.g. text, picture, another stream like webcam) and multiple audio channels etc.. It also works for both streaming directly (to a service like twitch or YouTube) and recording. There is even an option to output as a virtual webcam (to be used by something like skype, zoom etc.).

OBS is available for both Windows, MacOS and Linux.

To crop without the crop options for input devices:

[image: screenshot of adjustment]

Comment: It is odd that I don't see `Screen` as you do, please see update in OP.

Comment: @SoftTimur I meant `Display capture`. Sorry I have mine set to German and translated wrong. But if that doesn't work you can also give `window capture` a go.

Comment: I don't see `Advanced Settings` to specify the size of crop in my OBS (windows 26.0.2).

Comment: @SoftTimur Hm that is weird. in that case you can either try one of the other input options or resize the window in obs to be bigger than the recorded area. I will add a screenshot.

Comment: OK, I customized the size of canvas, use `Window Capture`, and adjusted the area to record. It works. Thank you.

Comment: @SoftTimur You're welcome. I would also recommend looking at the official guides and such at https://obsproject.com/help if you want to try some more advanced options.